# ASP.NETX evento onkeydown condicional

Tags: asp.net, asp

Tenho um formulário em ASP com 2 divs com alguns campos pra preencher, mas existe uma flag no perfil do usuário que pode, ou não, ocultar uma delas

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                dvValidade.Visible = (bool)Session["confVal"]; //valido o perfil
    }
```

Div:

```
<div class="ConfProdText" id="dvValidade" runat="server" visible="true">
    --Codigo aqui
</div>
```

Até aqui isso funciona, o problema é que na div **anterior**, existe um `<asp:TextBox>` com uma função para clicar no botão enviar:

```
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQntdeConfe" class="textbox" Width="89px" MaxLength="11" Rows="1" AutoComplete="off" runat="server" onFocus="this.select();" type="number" step="0.001" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 9) document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnEnviar').click()"/>

<div>
```

O que eu preciso, é que, quando a for `dvValidade.Visible = true`, que a condição dentro do `onkeydown` do textbox não execute

**O QUE EU JÁ FIZ:**

tentei mudar a condição para:

```
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 9 && $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dvValidade').is(':hidden')) document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnEnviar').click()"
```

e coloquei a `dvValidade` com `display="none"`:

```
<div style="margin-left: 1px; text-align: left;" class="ConfProdText" id="dvValidade" runat="server" visible="true" display="none">
.
.
.
</div>
```

mas não consegui alterar o valor da propriedade `display`, e mesmo estando `none` ele tenta procurar o textbox

Comment: Quando dá tab e a data validade tá escondida chama o click do enviar é isso ? E não funcionou ? Se não funcionou o que aconteceu ? Deu algum erro na consola ? Consegue ver o display none no `<div>` ? `console.log($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dvValidade').is(':hidden')))` mostra-lhe o que ?

Comment: @Isac Quando ela ta escondida, funciona, ela chama o click do botão e ta ok. o problema é quando não está, pq quando passa para o campo `txtQntdeConfe` ele chama o campo, mas ainda existem 2 novos campos para serem preenchidos. o que eu preciso, é uma forma de, dentro do onkeydown, ele identificar se ta visível ou não, para ai sim decidir se executa o clique ou segue o comportamento normal do TAB

Comment: eu sei que é um pouco estranho, mas essa pagina ta sendo feita pra rodar em um coletor de código de barras, e o botão de mais fácil acesso é o TAB

Comment: Mas ainda não respondeu a algumas das questões que fiz no primeiro comentário, e em particular em relação ao `console.log`. De qualquer forma isso parece claramente problema de html e javascript, e não relacionado com asp.net, mas pela sua pergunta não está claro o que não está a funcionar e qual o problema que tem. A minha sugestão é que você crie um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, através do snippet da pergunta para que seja fácil de nós vermos e reproduzirmos o problema.